# Can Qt creator show each output of the application in new terminal?

Tags: qt-creator

I use Qt creator to work on C++ code. The problem is that I would like to compare two different outputs, but every time I run the code Qt creator deletes the previous output in the terminal, therefore I can not compare two outputs. Tools->Options->Environment->System->Terminal has option /usr/bin/gnome-terminal-x.

Is it possible to make Qt creator show each new output of the application in new terminal?  I use Qt Creator 3.6.1, my OS is Ubuntu 14.04.4